# How to enable Legacy mode on Lenovo IdeaPad d330

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, legacy

If I boot into the UEFI firmware using F2 and disable Secure Boot, there is no Legacy mode available in the Boot Mode *(apparently there should be and I would use it to use my YUMI boot disk)*.

I have updated the UEFI firmware to the latest version and restarted many times.

[How to boot from USB disk in the BIOS (Boot Menu) - ideapad, Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-d-series-laptops/d330-10igm/solutions/ht500207-how-to-boot-from-usb-disk-in-the-bios-boot-menu-windows-8-windows-10-ideapadlenovo-laptops)

Comment: Curiously secure boot no longer seems to work. If I enable it via the BIOS setting, the button says it's enabled but it is red and the system reports it disabled.

Comment: Is your disk formatted in MBR? Legacy boot is impossible with GPT.

Comment: Why exactly is [CSM \[Legacy\] Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) attempting to be enabled? There is literally _only_ one use case for doing so: accessing a legacy OPROM, and upon exiting the OPROM, CSM [Legacy] Mode should be re-disabled. **The _sole_ purpose of CSM [Legacy] Mode was to allow distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 to boot** _(all distros have supported EFI boot since 2017, with Windows supporting EFI boot since Win7)_. This seems like a fundamental misunderstanding of what CSM [Legacy] Mode is and what it's for, and/or an X Y Problem.

Comment: There are ways to convert older BIOS-only ISOs to support EFI boot, and many of the non-updated BIOS-only boot ISOs have tools that are built-in to [Hiren's BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/). CSM [Legacy] Mode causes UEFI firmware [64bit] to emulate BIOS [16bit] within a 32bit environment, of which causes performance degradation - boot times increase from ~10s to 45s+, GPT can't be used if Windows, etc. Since CSM [Legacy] Mode serves literally no purpose today, motherboard OEMs began phasing it out of their motherboard firmware several years ago, possibly explaining the missing option